# Symfony 4: Cannot access admin roles. Access Denied

Tags: security, roles, symfony4

I'm learning Symfony 4 and try to make follow Symfony 4 Documentation to create an app.

I do follow this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) to make admin roles.

But when I access path `/admin`, it's always `"Access Denied."`

I read many article in Symfony Documentation page and StackOverflow but can not found the way to solve it. Here is my setting

```
//config/packges/security.yaml

security:

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin123
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
              default_target_path: index
              always_use_default_target_path: true

            logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /index

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And here is the Symfony Debug log:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: "Access Denied." at C:\xampp\htdocs\aimer-mvc\vendor\symfony\security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener.php line 68

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your app with *admin* / *admin123*, you have to allow `in_memory` provider in your firewall :

only for http_basic :

```
security:

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin123
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic:
                provider: in_memory
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
              default_target_path: index
              always_use_default_target_path: true

            logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /index

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

for form_login as well :

```
security:

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        both_providers:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, our_db_provider]
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin123
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: both_providers
            form_login:
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
              default_target_path: index
              always_use_default_target_path: true

            logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /index

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html for examples...

Comment: I tried to fix it as your code but it still not change. Any way thank you so much. I will try some ways :))

Comment: What login/password do you use for your test ?

Comment: I access roles /admin from /index but Access Denied. Even login or not, it still Access Denied. Many thanks for help.

Comment: When I use only providers: in_memory, I can access admin roles, but when use chain_providers include in_memory user and user load from database, Access Deneid.

Comment: Many thank @AlterPHP for help. Finally, I found the way to fix this problem. It is manually edit user role from ROLE_USER to ROLE_ADMIN in database/app_user table/role column.